# TinyMCE merges A tags incorrectly

Tags: javascript, tinymce, rich-text-editor

I've got the following problem with TinyMCE:

I've inserted the following code into a TinyMCE instance:

```
<p><a href="/_pics/articles/large/WAbOlemChF.jpg" rel="gallery"><img class="img-center" src="/_pics/articles/WAbOlemChF.jpg" alt="b" /></a></p>
<p><a href="/_pics/articles/large/cT89QKCChs.jpg" rel="gallery"><img class="img-center" src="/_pics/articles/cT89QKCChs.jpg" alt="v" /></a></p>
```

This results is the following:

[image]

If I place the cursor as indicated in the image above, and I hit the DELETE key, I get the following:

[image]

So far, so good, except that when I check out the code, it looks like this:

```
<p><a href="/_pics/articles/large/cT89QKCChs.jpg" rel="gallery"><img class="img-center" src="/_pics/articles/WAbOlemChF.jpg" alt="b" /><img class="img-center" src="/_pics/articles/cT89QKCChs.jpg" alt="v" /></a></p>
```

Note, that the A tags have been merged. As you'd image this raises a big problem since the "href" attribute was different. I would've expected it to put both A tags in the same paragraph, but keep them distinct.

Is it a TinyMCE bug, or there's something in the configuration that I can tweak so it merges only identical A tags?

I'm using v3.5.6, jQuery version.

Comment: Managed to fix it in Firefox (by putting SPAN tags instead of P tags) and now it's broken in Chrome. This takes me back to the good old days of IE6 and Netscape Navigator.

Answer (score 0):

We had a lot of wierd delete behaviours probably due to the fact that browsers have bugs.
Solution was to take care of the delte process and executing an own action to bypass the default behaviour. For this we defined several scenarios where unwanted things happened and tried to isolate that cases in order to be able to correct it.

Comment: So, you're saying this is something that can't be fixed without going into Tinymce's source code? Unfortunately, for this project it's really a must to solve this type of scenario. Any ideas?

Comment: no, you do not have to go into the core code, you can do this using an own plugin (or the setup configuration paramter) and listen for the tinymce events onKeyDown and onKeyUp then you check if correction is needed and apply it (stop Propagation if necessary).

Comment: Well, it turns out that in Chrome (I was testing in Firefox) the initial code already looks like the second image, and you can't even place the cursor there and press DELETE. Also, if you place the cursor after the first image (on the same row) and press DELETE, nothing happens. It's not ideal, but better that Firefox anyway. Anyway, your suggestion sounds interesting, but it's way over my head.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want TinyMCE to mess with your code, just give it a class. This works in the WordPress implementation, so hopefully it will work for you too.

Example..

```
<p class="image"><a href="/_pics/articles/large/WAbOlemChF.jpg" rel="gallery"><img class="img-center" src="/_pics/articles/WAbOlemChF.jpg" alt="b" /></a></p>
<p class="image"><a href="/_pics/articles/large/cT89QKCChs.jpg" rel="gallery"><img class="img-center" src="/_pics/articles/cT89QKCChs.jpg" alt="v" /></a></p>
```

The class doesn't have to be defined, just give it an empty class if need be. Point is, TinyMCE won't remove anything that has a class and hence your code should remain untouched.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. Even with different classes on the paragraphs and anchors, it still merges them.

Comment: That's a shame. Must be the way WP has it implemented. Sorry I couldn't help. Could you perhaps try `CKEditor` instead?

Comment: I hope I won't have to resort to that, since the project is complete save for this tiny bug :(